# How to enter Ge'ez alphabet (Tigrinyan language) in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, input-method

[Ge'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_language) is an East-African alphabet.

Using the powerful [Eclipse IDE editor](http://www.eclipse.org/), it is possible to switch "Input Type" to *Tigrinya (EZ+)*. Typing the 5 letters *selam* will then result in the 3 Ge'ez letters: ሰላም

I am looking for a similar feature for OpenOffice, LibreOffice, gedit or Gnome in general. I have been able to [set this up in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56027/how-to-enter-geez-alphabet-tigrinyan-language), but I have no success with Mint.

I am using Linux Mint 17.2 'Rafaela'. Answers are welcome for CINNAMON or MATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this on Linux Mint 17.2 'Rafaela' Cinnamon 62-bit.

1. Install the package [ibus-m17n [image: Install ibus-m17n]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ibus-m17n)
2. Select *Keyboard Input Methods* from the startmenu **or** which starts *ibus-setup*:

[image: Keyboard Input Methods in the mnu]

3. Select *sera m17n* as a new Input Method and press *Add*. Close this dialog.

[image: Add sera m17n as a new IBus Input Method]

4. Go to *System Settings -> Language -> Input Method* and check two things here: First input method must be set to **IBus**, secondly see if IBus missing components it offers you to install here. If they are missing install them.

[image: Check that IBus is the Input Method]

5. Logout, Login or Reboot
6. From now on, pressing Ctrl+Space will switch between all added input methods:

[image]